# How do I cast int** to void**?

Tags: c++, casting, void, void-pointers

With the following snippet:

```cpp
int n = 11;
int* c = &n;
void** v = &c;
```

I receive the following error in visual studio:

> the value of type `int**` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `void **`.

This works fine:

```cpp
int n = 11;
int* c = &n;
void* v = c;
```

But this code snippet is for a larger problem in someone's library.

What am I doing wrong with casting a variable to  `void**`?

## Complete Example

Using the [caen digitizer library](https://www.caen.it/products/caendigitizer-library/) the way they try to collect data from the peripheral device has this prototype:

```cpp
/******************************************************************************
* X742_DecodeEvent(char *evtPtr, void **Evt)
* Decodes a specified event stored in the acquisition buffer writing data in Evt memory
* Once used the Evt memory MUST be deallocated by the caller!
*
* [IN]  EventPtr : pointer to the requested event in the acquisition buffer (MUST BE NULL)
* [OUT] Evt      : event structure with the requested event data
*                : return  0 = Success; 
******************************************************************************/
int32_t X742_DecodeEvent(char *evtPtr, void **Evt);
```

And this is the implementation:

```cpp
int32_t X742_DecodeEvent(char *evtPtr, void **Evt) {
    CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t *Event;
    uint32_t *buffer;
    char chanMask;
    uint32_t j,g,size;
    uint32_t *pbuffer;
    uint32_t eventSize;
    int evtSize,h;

    evtSize = *(long *)evtPtr & 0x0FFFFFFF;
    chanMask = *(long *)(evtPtr+4) & 0x0000000F;
    evtPtr += EVENT_HEADER_SIZE;
    buffer = (uint32_t *) evtPtr;
    pbuffer = (uint32_t *) evtPtr;
    eventSize = (evtSize * 4) - EVENT_HEADER_SIZE;
    if (eventSize == 0) return -1;
    Event = (CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t *) malloc(sizeof(CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t));
    if (Event == NULL) return -1;
    memset( Event, 0, sizeof(CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t));
    for (g=0; g<X742_MAX_GROUPS; g++) {
        if ((chanMask >> g) & 0x1) {
        for (j=0; j<MAX_X742_CHANNEL_SIZE; j++) {
            Event->DataGroup[g].DataChannel[j]= malloc(X742_FIXED_SIZE * sizeof (float));
            if (Event->DataGroup[g].DataChannel[j] == NULL) {
                for (h=j-1;h>-1;h++) free(Event->DataGroup[g].DataChannel[h]);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        size=V1742UnpackEventGroup(g,pbuffer,&(Event->DataGroup[g]));
        pbuffer+=size;
        Event->GrPresent[g] = 1;    
        } 
        else {
            Event->GrPresent[g] = 0;
            for (j=0; j<MAX_X742_CHANNEL_SIZE; j++) {
                Event->DataGroup[g].DataChannel[j] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    *Evt = Event;
    return 0;
}
```

I use this by:

```cpp
CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t* Evt = NULL; // Creating my event pointer
//Doing some config of the device
X742_DecodeEvent(evtptr, &Evt); //Decode the event data for me to read (Throws error)
```

Hope this gives some context.

Comment: void ** v = (void**)&c;

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Success, do you mind writing an answer explaining why this casting works?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That's really terrible advice.  All you've done is suppress the compiler warning.

Comment: Why is this question even tagged c++. Everything screams c.

Comment: @TarickWelling  Sorry I'm not to strong on what the difference nuances are. Ill change the tag.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes. What else do you expect with that sort of question?

Comment: @Tsangares How do you compile the code? If you use a C compiler, use C tag. If you compile as C++, tag it as C++. It's customary to not tag both unless necessary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am compiling as C++ but the libraries I included are C. I thought I was allowed to do that. Maybe if I switch that it will suppress this warning.

Comment: @TarickWelling Out of curiosity how did you tell this was C and not C++?

Comment: @Tsangares In general, C is not compilable as C++. There exists a subset of C that is valid C++, and if the library is purposefully written in that subset, then you can do that. But if the library happens to be incidentally valid C++, then a later version may stop being valid.

Comment: @Tsangares As for how to recognise that this is probably not C++; a few examples: `malloc` is typically not used in C++ (except when interfacing with C libraries that require it). `memset` is even less used in C++, as value initialisation is simpler and more robust.

Comment: Any pointer (except a pointer to a member, which is something different, despite the name) can be implicitly converted to a `void *`.    That rule is not recursive, so `int **` cannot be converted to a `void **`.

Comment: The omission of RAII, usage of macros, malloc/memset, raw buffer usage, type juggling with pointers. This code is idiomatic for C not for C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void**` means a pointer to a `void*` object. But there is no `void*` object in that code to point at! `void**` does NOT mean "a pointer to any kind of pointer", so please avoid using it as such.  If you have a pointer to something which might be an `int*`, might be a `double*`, or etc., `void*` is a better type than `void**`. Even better would be a template or `std::variant` or `std::any`.

But if you have to use a library that is using `void**` to mean "a pointer to a pointer to a type unknown at compile time" or something like that, you might need to create a `void*` pointer to work with, or might need to add in casts to get around the fact that the compiler doesn't like this conversion (for good reason). The problem is, there are at least two reasonable ways to do this! (They will end up doing exactly the same thing on many common computer architectures, but this is not guaranteed.)

```
// LibraryFunc1 takes a void** argument that somehow means an int* pointer.
// But which call is correct?
int* data_in = generate_data();
LibraryFunc1(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&data_in)); // ?
void* p1 = data_in;
LibraryFunc1(&p1); // ?

// LibraryFunc2 returns a void** argument that somehow means an int* pointer.
void** p2 = LibraryFunc2();
int* data_out_1 = static_cast<int*>(*p2); // ?
int* data_out_2 = *reinterpret_cast<int**>(p2); // ?
```

Based on the function definition shown, the safe usage is unfortunately:

```
void* tmpEvt;
X742_DecodeEvent(evtptr, &tmpEvt);
auto* Evt = static_cast<CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t*>(tmpEvt);
```

since the library function assumes at `*Evt = Event;` that `*Evt` is actually a `void*` object it can modify.  It may usually work to do the simpler thing instead:

```
CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t* Evt = NULL;
X742_DecodeEvent(evtptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&Evt));
```

but this is undefined behavior by the C++ Standard, and might do the wrong thing on some architectures.

You could make the correct way easier by wrapping it in a function:

```
inline CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t* Get_X742_DecodeEvent(char* evtPtr)
{
    void* tmpEvt;
    X742_DecodeEvent(evtPtr, &tmpEvt);
    return static_cast<CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t*>(tmpEvt);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong with casting a variable to void**?

There is no meaningful way to convert `int**` to `void**`, so what you're trying to do is wrong.

What you may do is

```
int n = 11;
void* c = &n;
void** v = &c;
```

But without a complete example, it is not possible to say whether applies to your problem.

Comment: Added the context of the problem for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply how the language works.

`void *` pointers  get special treatment: a pointer to an arbitrary type can be converted to a pointer to `void` (as long as doing so doesn't remove [cv-qualifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) from the pointer).

`void **` gets none of that special treatment. It's just a regular pointer type, like `int **`.

---

> ```
> int32_t X742_DecodeEvent(char *evtPtr, void **Evt)
> ```

Since you want to pass `CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t **` to your function, you should change the parameter type accordingly: `CAEN_DGTZ_X742_EVENT_t **Evt`.

---

In comments you were suggested to use `void ** v = (void**)&c;`.

While you could *probably* make it work in practice, strictly speaking any access to `*v` would violate [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and cause undefined behavior. I wouldn't use that solution.